# Using a common buffer to read from inputstream and to write to outputstream

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, inputstream

I read from network socket's input stream into the `buffer`

```
count = input.read(buffer)
```

Then in next line, i'm printing the read contents using

```
str = new String(buffer,0,count);
Log.e("str",str);
```

Then i try to write it to a `PipedOutputStream` of an `PipedInputStream`

```
pipedOutputStream .write(buffer);
```

where,

```
pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream)
```

The problem is the thread is blocking at `pipedOutputStream .write(buffer);`

Below is to confirm that, taken from Thread debugging tool of DDMS,

[image: The image showing below quoted contents in DDMS thread viewer]

```
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)   
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401) 
  at java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:394)    
  at java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:176)    
  at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:106)  
  at java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:147)    
  at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)   
  at com.example.Receiver.run(DRCReceiver.java:104)
```

*Can any one tell me, why the following is not working(**blocking the thread**) (grouping all statements)*

```
count = input.read(buffer)
str = new String(buffer,0,count);
Log.e("str",str);
pipedOutputStream .write(buffer);
```

but the following is working(**not blocking the thread**) .

```
count = input.read(buffer)
str = new String(buffer,0,count);
Log.e("str",str);
pipedOutputStream .write(str.getBytes());
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @anders_reimer, tat's not a stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html). Here you can see: "Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended". Usually you need another thread that attempts to read some data.

Comment: Acutally PipedStreams are for the purpose. And I used them as it is supposed to. I've created pipedInputStream in one thread, and read the pipe from another thread.